# What language for creating background process (service app) on BB OS 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I am starting a blackberry os 10 development.
What programming languages can be used to create BB OS 10 background process (service app)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background apps, or better known as [headless](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/) are written in C/C++. Check out [tutorial](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/create_headless_app.html)

Comment: is C++ the only option?
What about java and I also read somewhere that python and pyside can create bb10 app.

Comment: I don't know about that. There is a [python](http://blackberry.github.io/Community/Python.html) project, but that's all I know